# How can I read data from external url (json) and print it with javascript in another html page?

Tags: javascript, php, html, json

I need to print value **TotalPostNotificationCount** in my external html with javascript or php.

This is the JSON:

```
{
   "DayPostCount": 1,
   "TotalPostNotificationCount": 7381
}
```

from url: https://app.jobka.cz/Analyze/Analyze.json

Comment: `var analyze = JSON.parse('{"DayPostCount":1,"TotalPostNotificationCount":7381}');
console.log(analyze.TotalPostNotificationCount );` ? Or `document.innerHTML += analyze.TotalPostNotificationCount `

Comment: Can you add details how you are get this JSON and where are you want to print it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put there a way of doing it with Ajax. As mentioned in the other answer you have to set the CORS header on the server side.

JS method using AJAX :

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(() => {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://app.jobka.cz/Analyze/Analyze.json',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(result) {
      console.table(result); // code in case of result
    },

    error: function(error) {
      console.log(error); //error handler
    }

  });
})
</script>
```

PHP Method using CURL :

```
   $ch = curl_init('https://app.jobka.cz/Analyze/Analyze.json');              
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
   $result = curl_exec($ch);
   print_r(json_decode($result));
   curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it using plan JavaScript as below

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.overrideMimeType("application/json");
req.open('GET', 'https://app.jobka.cz/Analyze/Analyze.json', true);
req.onload  = function() {
   var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
   console.log(jsonResponse)
};
req.send(null);
```

But problem is you need to set the CORS on the API side as you can't just use the data anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Or using fetch:

```
fetch('https://app.jobka.cz/Analyze/Analyze.json').then(data=> console.log(data.DayPostCount))
```